# How to calculate future value of investment with Pandas when interest rates and payments vary over time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, quantitative-finance

Let's assume that I would like to know how the value of my invested money changes over time. I have the following data in Pandas DataFrame:

```
            contribution    monthly_return
2020-01-01  91.91           np.Nan
2020-02-01  102.18          0.037026
2020-03-01  95.90          -0.012792
2020-04-01  117.89         -0.009188    
2020-05-01  100.44          0.011203
2020-06-01  98.89           0.053917
2020-07-01  106.10         -0.049397
2020-08-01  112.55          0.062375
2020-09-01  103.16         -0.063198
```

...and so on. Every month I invest additional sum of money to my "fund" (contribution). Monthly return shows how the value of my money changed during last month.

I would like to add additional column, where I could find information on current value of my investment in every month (so I can plot it on a graph). As far as I know, I cannot use any of numpy financial functions (such as np.fv()) because contributions and rates changes over time. I can cumulative sum contributions, but I don't know how to add profit and loss on investment.

This may be a trivial question, but I am completely stuck and I have wasted more hours on this problem than I could ever admit. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your investment on `2020-01-01` is 91.91. What time period `monthly_return`  -0.038305 on the same day corresponds to? Dec 2019? Do you mean you had some money in your account prior to `2020-01-01`? What are the units of `monthly_return`, $, %?

Comment: Let's say we start with 0$ of investment. Every month I contribute indicated amount of money. The abovementioned example is just a sample i extracted from my data - I made a mistake, there should not be any monthly return on the first month. Every next monthly_return corresponds to the diffrence between the month and previous month.
Units of monthly_returns are %.
I hope I cleared any doubts!

Comment: Units of monthly return,%? Monthly, per annum, simple, compounded?

Comment: Edited my previous comment. Monthly, simple returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a `df`:

```
print(df)
            contribution  monthly_return
2020-01-01         91.91             NaN
2020-02-01        102.18        0.037026
2020-03-01         95.90       -0.012792
2020-04-01        117.89       -0.009188
2020-05-01        100.44        0.011203
2020-06-01         98.89        0.053917
2020-07-01        106.10       -0.049397
2020-08-01        112.55        0.062375
2020-09-01        103.16       -0.063198
```

Then let's find a multiplier your money grows monthly:

```
df['monthly_multiplier'] = 1 + df['monthly_return'].shift(-1)
print(df)
            contribution  monthly_return  monthly_multiplier
2020-01-01         91.91             NaN            1.037026
2020-02-01        102.18        0.037026            0.987208
2020-03-01         95.90       -0.012792            0.990812
2020-04-01        117.89       -0.009188            1.011203
2020-05-01        100.44        0.011203            1.053917
2020-06-01         98.89        0.053917            0.950603
2020-07-01        106.10       -0.049397            1.062375
2020-08-01        112.55        0.062375            0.936802
2020-09-01        103.16       -0.063198                 NaN
```

Finally we can iterate over rows and see how your wealth grows:

```
df['fv'] = 0
fv = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    fv = (fv+row['contribution'])*row['monthly_multiplier']
    df.loc[index,'fv']=fv
print(df)
            contribution  monthly_return  monthly_multiplier          fv
2020-01-01         91.91             NaN            1.037026   95.313060
2020-02-01        102.18        0.037026            0.987208  194.966728
2020-03-01         95.90       -0.012792            0.990812  288.194245
2020-04-01        117.89       -0.009188            1.011203  410.633607
2020-05-01        100.44        0.011203            1.053917  538.629162
2020-06-01         98.89        0.053917            0.950603  606.027628
2020-07-01        106.10       -0.049397            1.062375  756.546589
2020-08-01        112.55        0.062375            0.936802  814.171423
2020-09-01        103.16       -0.063198                 NaN         NaN
```

`df['fv']` is your wealth at the end of the stated month, or just prior your next contribution.

Comment: Thank you for very much your anwser! Unfortunately, it seems to me that your proposed solution is rather wrong. In your example, only the current contribution  is multiplied by the rate of return every month. Every monthly_return should also affect all the money that has been contributed in previous months. Think of it as an investment fund. Every month I contribute some extra cash, but the changes in value apply to all the money collected in the fund, not just to what I am currently contributing.

Comment: Corrected per your comment.